What size eye bolt for a chain?
I plan on using a eye bolt (or short pipe) to guide a metal chain around a trailer I want to secure. The chain's links are 3/8" in diameter. Each link is about 1-1/2" across and 2-1/4" long. I want to be able move the chain through the eyelet easily. I do not yet have access to the actual chain. What inside diameter of an eye bolt or pipe would allow for that?
Thanks in advance.

You want it ~1 3/4 to 2 inch inside diameter to pass 1.5 inch chain.  If just a guide needed, maybe think about a pulley.  Chain though an eye bolt/pipe will work as a slow saw/grinder in time(maybe years).
